# Setting up maven repo on Nexus server

Tags: java, xml, maven, repository, nexus

i'm trying downloading liabaries from nexus repository and it falied to download, with the next
error: "cannot resolve org.

this is the pom.xml i wrote-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-repo</id>
            <name>acme nexus</name>
            <url>our url (not relevant)</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvnTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

this is the settings.xml i wrote-

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>

        <server>
            <id>nexus-repo</id>
            <username>{our username}</username>
            <password>{our password}</password>
            <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
            <passphrase>{some ramdom password}</passphrase>
            <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
            <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
            <configuration></configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

can someone please help me and tell me where i did wrong?

Comment: You should define the consumption of artifacts in your settings.xml file and **NOT** in your pom file...

Answer (score 0):

You should use either <password> or <privateKey> & <passphtrase> but not both. See https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers